# MVC Partial View not returning data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a page with search parameters and a grid in bottom of the page (which is partial page). When user enters a search criteria and click the Find button. I am calling a Search method on a controller and getting the filtered data and then calling Partial View. But some how I am getting blank page. When I am trying to read the return data, it is giving "undefined". Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: do you use "@{ Html.RenderPartial("Your_Partial"); }" or "@{ Html.RenderAction("Your_Partial","Partial"); } " ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I am calling partial view from Controller method:                                                                                                         return PartialView("_EmployeeGrid");

Comment: check this https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: Below code is from "Find" button click event:

$.get('@Url.Action("Search", "EmployeeSearch")', {
              data: JSON.stringify({ EmployeeId: employeeId, EmployeeCounty: county })
          },
          function (data) {
              if (data.status == "Success") {
                  alert("success");
                  loadGrid();
              } else {
                  alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
              }
          });

Comment: Search Method in Controller:

public PartialViewResult Search(string data)
{

  //Data Manipulation

  return PartialView("_EmployeeGrid");
}

Comment: Another method in controller, which is called while DocumentReady:

public JsonResult GetEmployeeLists(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, EmployeeModel model)  
{
   // Data Manipulation
  return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


Still going to Error section not to success.

Comment: public JsonResult GetEmployeeLists(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, EmployeeModel model)  
{
   // Data Manipulation
  return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

This method GetEmplyeeLists should be called when the partial view is called.

Partial View:

<table id="_employeeGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="_employeeGridGPager" style="text-align: center;">
</div>

I am using JQGrid for diplaying data. I have loadgrid() function in $(document).ready(function () of Index page.